# Button On Action Property -> Add a Change Listener

Tags: java, javafx

i have a Button and i want to add there a onActionProperty, in every Action-Event i would like to make some stuff.

How can i add it to the Button?

My Example:

```
m_popupSwitch.onActionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends EventHandler<ActionEvent>> arg0, EventHandler<ActionEvent> arg1, EventHandler<ActionEvent> arg2)
            {
                System.out.println("OUTPUT ");
            }
        });
```

I can add it like in my Example, but it does not work, so how can i fix my code, that i get an Event every Time when the onActionProperty changes...

The Main - Problem is, that i have a ToggleButton which is Groups to a ToggleGroup. Now i want to get every Event in this Region on that Action Property. I hope you can help me.

Comment: I don't really get your question. Doesn't `Button` have the `onActionProperty` API?

Comment: @GGrec add some new to the questions

Comment: Your code will be executed when the listener registered with the button via `m_popupSwitch.setOnAction(...)` changes (i.e. the listener you have will be invoked every time you call `m_popupSwitch.setOnAction(...);`). I don't think that is what you want. Can you edit the question so it is clearer ("I have a ToggleButton which is Groups to a ToggleGroup" doesn't make any sense at all, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to act uppon s select AND deselect of a toggle button try:

```
    ToggleButton first = new ToggleButton("A");
    ToggleButton second = new ToggleButton("B");
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    first.setToggleGroup(group);
    second.setToggleGroup(group);
    second.selectedProperty().addListener((p, ov, nv) -> {
        System.out.println("Changed");
    });
```

The difference of the listers can be shown using:

```
    ToggleButton first = new ToggleButton("A");
    ToggleButton second = new ToggleButton("B");
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    first.setToggleGroup(group);
    second.setToggleGroup(group);
    second.selectedProperty().addListener((p, o, n) -> {
        System.out.println("Changed "+p.getValue());
    });
    second.setOnAction(a -> {
        System.out.println("Action");
    });
    second.onActionProperty().addListener((p, o, n) ->{
        System.out.println("OnAction");

    });
```

Where a click on B (second) will print:

```
  Changed true
  Action
```

And a follow up click on A (first) will print:

```
  Changed false
```

So:

1. The onAction() Listener (setOnAction) is called if someone click on THIS button
2. The selectedProperty() listener is called if the toggle state 'selected' changes, also if it is deselected by a click on another button of this toggle group
3. The onActionProperty() listener is only called, if someone removed or adds a new listener using the setOnAction() method.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
m_popupSwitch.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
{
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("OUTPUT");
    }
});
```

[**Reference Here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm)

Comment: No i don't will get that one! This Button is a ToggleButton, when another Toggle is selected, i want to handle that event ...

Comment: Then can you edit your question? Your question as it stands doesn't ask that at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a listener to a button, you register set a EventHandler, whose handle method is called when the button is pressed. Like this:

```
 m_popupSwitch.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("OUTPUT ");

                }
            });
```

Comment: No i don't will get that one! This Button is a ToggleButton, when another Toggle is selected, i want to handle that event ..